# Implementing Single-user OAuth in Android

Tags: java, android, api, oauth

I want to implement single User OAuth in android side or in other words need some API for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [signpost](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/), it's a Java library for OAuth (1.0a, 2.0 is not yet supported).

Comment: Is the library suitable for Android?

Comment: It not for Single-user OAuth but implementing OAuth with its complete dance. The scenario is somewhat like that ... server side is implemented by using Single-user OAuth strategy and I have to customize myself accordingly.